# Spring MVC 4 is not generating json root object by default

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a a controller class that was previously written using spring mvc 3 but for some reasons we decided to update the spring version to the 4.1.4. 
After this change this controller stop working as it worked before...
In the previous version this below code returned like this: departmentList: {....} with this departmentList in the beginning but right now it is returning just as a simple array: [{...},{...}]

```
new ModelAndView().addObject(departmentList);
```

My configuration is on xml.

```
<bean id="cnManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="useJaf" value="true"/>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
       p:targetMethod="disable">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>    

<bean id="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"
      p:supportedMediaTypes="application/json" 
      p:objectMapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>          

<bean id="mappingJacksonJsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"
      p:extractValueFromSingleKeyModel="true" 
      p:objectMapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>

<!--
    View resolver that delegates to other view resolvers based on the content type
-->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
   <!-- All configuration is now done by the manager - since Spring V3.2 -->
   <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="cnManager"/>
   <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>                
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" p:extractValueFromSingleKeyModel="true" 
                p:objectMapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
        </list>
    </property>
   <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. 
I needed to changed my defaultViews to be like this:

```
<property name="defaultViews">
        <list>                
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
```

Now it works as expected with no code change.

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem. This code help me to generate pure json array.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/getAll/{isDeletedShow}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ModelAndView getAllEntity(@PathVariable boolean isDeletedShow) {
    try {
        MappingJackson2JsonView mapping = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        List<EntityBank> b = service.findAll(isDeletedShow);

        mapping.setEncoding(JsonEncoding.UTF8);
        mapping.setPrettyPrint(true);
        mapping.setPrefixJson(false);
        mapping.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);            

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.getModelMap().addAttribute("BanksList", b);
        modelAndView.setView(mapping);

        return modelAndView;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }

    return null;
}
```